# What protocol is used when reading from a local private MSMQ?

Tags: msmq

According to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms811053.aspx reading from a *remote* queue means invoking a RPC call. What about when reading from a local queue? Is RPC also used?

The scenario that I'm trying to work with is multiple services reading from a local queue. With a remote queue RPC will create a blocking call perventing other services from reading from the remote queue. But if the queue is local, will calls still be blocked as MSMQ process the request from one service at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local access to receive messages uses Local RPC.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738291(WS.10).aspx

The procedure is the same. If you do not open the queue for sharing (i.e. you specified MQ_DENY_RECEIVE_SHARE) then you'll get blocking regardless of local or remote activity.

Cheers
John Breakwell

Comment: So does receiving from a local queue create a blocking call? MSMQ best practice is to retrieve from local queues not remote queues. If had multiple processes receiving from a local queue, would each process create a blocking call?

Comment: Blocking calls are not something I've looked into before. If there is blocking then it shouldn't matter if you use local or remote queues (apparant from the normal performance difference between local and remote queue access). I had always assumed blocking was at the message level.
Are you specifying MQ_DENY_RECEIVE_SHARE or MQ_DENY_NONE?